# How can I customize which URL the Django admin interface points to?

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, server-administration

I have a server running Django's Gunicorn server on 127.0.0.1:8000 behind an Apache proxy. This works well for most purposes, but the Django admin interface, when editing model contents, saves a change and then redirects to `http://localhost:8000/abc/xyz` leaving for slight confusion for the user. (In this case the users are a few trusted users, so I can address this with user education if I have to, but I would rather not have to.)

How can I ask the Django admin interface to treat its base url as http://domain.com/ and direct the user to something appropriate after editing model instances?

Comment: There should be some Apache setup to forward appropriate http headers to Django.

Comment: Is the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` header given to Django?